# ¿Qué es refactorización, para qué sirve y cuando aplicarla?

Tags: refactoring

Soy nuevo en la empresa y herede este código que implementa el juego del gato tradicional, sobre una matriz 3x3.

Ahora me piden que lo transforme a un juego NxN, y me dijeron que tenía que refactorizarlo para hacerlo más simple.

¿Qué es refactorizar un código?

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){


char matriz[3][ 3], opc;
int i, j;

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
        matriz[i][j]=' ';
        printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
     }
    printf("\n");
}

int fila, col, ganador=0, turno=1;
    //para jugador 1
    do{
        if(turno%2==1){
            do{
                scanf("%d", &fila);
                scanf("%d", &col);
                //ciclo para cuando el usuario ingrese coordenadas invalidas
                if(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2){
                }
            }while(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2);
            
            matriz[fila][col]='x';
            
            for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                    printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            turno++;
            
        //para jugador dos
        } else if(turno%2==0){
            do{
                scanf("%d", &fila);
                scanf("%d", &col);
                
                //ciclo para cuando el usuario ingrese coordenadas invalidas
                if(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2){
                }
            } while(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2);
            
            matriz[fila][col]='o';
                            
            for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                    printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            turno++;
        }
        
        if(matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][2]
            || matriz[1][0] == 'x' && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][2]
                || matriz[2][0] == 'x' && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][1] && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][2]
                    
                    || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][0] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][0]
                        || matriz[0][1] == 'x' && matriz[0][1] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][1] == matriz[2][1]
                            || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][2] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][2]
                                
                                || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                    || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][0]){
            ganador=1;
            printf("1\n");
        }
                                    
                                    if(matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][2]
                                        || matriz[1][0] == 'o' && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][2]
                                            || matriz[2][0] == 'o' && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][1] && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                                
                                                || matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][0] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][0]
                                                    || matriz[0][1] == 'o' && matriz[0][1] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][1] == matriz[2][1]
                                                        || matriz[0][2] == 'o' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][2] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][2]
                                                            
                                                            || matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                                                || matriz[0][2] == 'o' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][0]){
                                        ganador=1;
                                        printf(" 2\n");
                                    }                                                                    
    } while(ganador != 1);
   
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nota: Se usan ejemplos en C, pero la técnica es agnóstica]

Refactorizar un código significa transformar su código fuente sin alterar sus resultados. Esto se hace para simplificarlo, reducir duplicaciones, eliminar código muerto y hacerlo más comprensible, por ende, más fácil de mantener y actualizar.

Se aplica sobre código funcionando (lógica correcta), y procede iterativamente, aplicando una transformación tras otra.

En este ejemplo, como se trata de hacer el juego multidimensional, partimos por reemplazar todas las menciones al tamaño del juego por una constante especificada por un `#define`. También nos convendría dar nombres a los caracteres usados para representar una celda vacía o bien ocupada por un jugador. Eso lo hacemos declarando un `enum` que nos da el rango de posibles valores para la variable.

```
#define DIM 3
enum valor_celda {VACIA = '+', PLAYER_1 = 'X', PLAYER_2 = '0'};
```

Luego revisamos el fuente cambiando todas los '3' por `DIM` y las constantes `' ', 'x' y 'o'` por los respectivos nombres VACIA, PLAYER_1 y PLAYER_2

Lo siguiente normalmente dividir el código en funciones de pequeño tamaño. Para eso se recorre el código identificando trozos que realicen funciones específicas y extrayendolo a funciones.

En el caso mostrado, tenemos este trozo

```
for(i=0; i<DIM; i++){
    for(j=0; j<DIM; j++){
        matriz[i][j]=VACIA;
        printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
     }
    printf("\n");
}
```

y lo voy a mover a una función aparte. También voy a eliminar los `printf`, porque no se debe mezclar operación (poner en cero la matriz) con e/s (imprimir la matriz).

```
void matriz_zero(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Inicializa las celdas con el caracter VACIA
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            m[i][j] = VACIA;
        }
    }
}
```

Notese que paso la matriz como parámetro en lugar de usar una variable global. Esto me da versatilidad, pues el programa podría emplear más de una matriz sin necesidad de cambios. Hay que evitar las variables globales.

Y para imprimir la matriz, cosa que hay que hacer en varias partes, defino una función de impresión:

```
void imprimir_matriz(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Imprime la matriz.
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            printf(" %c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Ahora el programa está un poco más simple. El comienzo del original queda así:

```
int main(){
    char matriz[DIM][DIM], opc;
    int i, j;

    matriz_zero(matriz);
    imprimir_matriz(matriz);
    int fila, col, ganador=0, turno=1;

    //para jugador 1
    do{
```

Si miramos lo que sigue, vemos que se trata de ir alternando entre dos jugadores y claramente todo el código está duplicado:

```
        if(turno%2==1){
            do{
                scanf("%d", &fila);
                scanf("%d", &col);
                //ciclo para cuando el usuario ingrese coordenadas invalidas
                if(matriz[fila][col] == PLAYER_1 || matriz[fila][col] == PLAYER_2 || fila > DIM-1 || col > DIM-1){
                }
            } while(matriz[fila][col] == PLAYER_1 || matriz[fila][col] == PLAYER_2 || fila > DIM-1 || col > DIM-1);
            
            matriz[fila][col]=PLAYER_1;
            
            for(i=0; i<DIM; i++){
                for(j=0; j<DIM; j++){
                    printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            turno++;
```

Aquí hay dos acciones separadas:

- Pedir las coordenadas de la celda a llenar, revisar que este vacía y llenarla.
- Imprimirla.

por lo que naturalmente dividiré el trozo en dos partes. Como ya tengo lista la impresión, sólo me queda ingresar las coordenadas y poblar la celda:

```
int pedir_celda(char m[DIM][DIM], char marca) {
    //  Pide una celda, valida que este vacia, la llena y revisa si es un ganador.
    int fila, col;
    while (1) {
        printf("--- Jugador %c ---\n", marca);
        printf("> fila: ");
        scanf("%d", &fila);
        printf("> columna: ");
        scanf("%d", &col);

        if (fila >= 0 && fila < DIM && col >= 0 && col < DIM) {
            if (m[fila][col] == VACIA) {
                m[fila][col] = marca;
                imprimir_matriz(m);
                break;
            } else {
                printf("Celda está ocupada\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Coordenadas fuera de rango\n");
        }
    }

    return revisar_ganador(m, fila, col);
}
```

Está función es general. Recibe en marca el caracter que identifica al jugador ('x' u '0'), por lo que sirva para ambos casos. Luego de poblar la celda, imprime la matriz para que el jugador vea el resultado de su movida.

Aquí hicimos pequeño cambio en la lógica: la función llama a `revisar_ganador`, por lo que al retornar ya se sabe si el jugador actual ha ganado la partida.

Con eso, `main` se reduce a:

```
int main() {
    int ganador = 0;
    int turno = 1;
    char matriz[DIM][DIM];

    matriz_zero(matriz);
    imprimir_matriz(matriz);

    while (!ganador) {
        if (turno) {
            ganador = pedir_celda(matriz, PLAYER_1);
        } else {
            ganador = pedir_celda(matriz, PLAYER_2);
        }
        turno = !turno;
    }
    printf("Ganaste!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Esto es mucho más entendible. En unas pocas líneas se presenta la lógica general de la aplicación, la que se estructura como una colección de funciones cortas, simples y con un sólo propósito.

Nos resta dar cuenta de estas líneas:

```
    if(matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][2]
        || matriz[1][0] == 'x' && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][2]
            || matriz[2][0] == 'x' && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][1] && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][2]
                
                || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][0] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][0]
                    || matriz[0][1] == 'x' && matriz[0][1] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][1] == matriz[2][1]
                        || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][2] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][2]
                            
                            || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][0]){
        ganador=1;
        printf("1\n");
    }
```

Claramente la intención es determinar si se lleno una fila, columna o diagonal, pero el código no es transformarlo en NxN. Hay que implementar una solución general, lo que no deriva del código original.

```
int revisar_diagonales(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Revisa si alguna de las dos diagonales maximas esta totalmente
    //  llena con la misma marca.
    //  Retorna True en tal caso.    
    int en_linea = 0;
    char marca = m[0][0];
    int count = 0;
    for (int fila = 0; fila < DIM; fila++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++) {
            if (m[fila][col] == marca)
                count++;
        }
    }
    if (count != DIM) {
        marca = m[0][DIM - 1];
        count = 0;
        for (int fila = 0; fila < DIM; fila++) {
            for (int col = DIM - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
                if (m[fila][col] == marca)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == DIM);
}

int revisar_ganador(char m[DIM][DIM], int fila, int col) {
    //  Revisa el jugador en la celda (fila, col) ha completado
    //  las celdas requeridas
    
    // Todas las celdas deben tener el mismo valor que (fila, col)
    char marca = m[fila][col];
    int i;

    //  Recorrer la misma fila contando las celdas iguales.
    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        if (m[fila][i] != marca)
            break;
    }
    if (i == DIM) {
        return 1;
    }

    //  Recorrer la misma columna contando las celdas iguales.
    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        if (m[fila][i] != marca)
            break;
    }
    if (i == DIM) {
        return 1;
    }

    return revisar_diagonales(m);
}
```

En este ejemplo no hemos detectado código muerto. Nada sobra en esta versión.

Eso es refactorizar. Cuando tengan problemas depurando un código (suyo o ajeno) apliquen refactorización para facilitar su comprensión.